# How to make my program take in any number of arrays rather than a set number?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I'm having a problem where I can't seem to make my program take in a number of arrays and organise them without having to specify a set number of arrays first. Here is the code, the main program is just calling these so I didn't put it in.

```
import SE112aClasses.GUI;
public class arraysort {    

    int[] array = new int[10];


    public void gatherint() {

        GUI gui = new GUI();


        for(int steps = 0; steps < 10; steps ++)
        {
            array[steps] = gui.getInt("Please enter an integer");

        }

    }


    public void organise() {

        boolean swap = true;
        int loops = 0;
        int y;
        while (swap) {
            swap = false;
            loops++;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length - loops; i++) {
                if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) 
                {
                    y = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[i + 1];
                    array[i + 1] = y;
                    swap = true;
                }

            }

        }

        System.out.println(array[0]);
        System.out.println(array[1]);
        System.out.println(array[2]);
        System.out.println(array[3]);
        System.out.println(array[4]);
        System.out.println(array[5]);
        System.out.println(array[6]);
        System.out.println(array[7]);
        System.out.println(array[8]);
        System.out.println(array[9]);

    }
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to make it so it takes in any number of integers(not a set amount) and can display them without having to prompt for the amount of integers they are going to input. I've tried a quite a few things but it just fails and doesn't even print anything. I'm new to arrays so if there is any reading material that I could use to help with this that would be greatly appreciated too, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the word "array" incorrectly. **You only have one array.** You want to make your program accept a number of **values**, a number which you do not know ahead of time.

There are several aspects to this problem:

1. If the size of the array is not known at compile-time, it needs to be determined at run time.
2. If the user doesn't know the size of the array before they have typed it in, you can use a sentinel value such as -1 or 999999 to indicate the end. (This is only really appropriate for homework - in the real world, you'd use a button, link or other UI element to stop entering data.)
3. You should use a loop to output an array.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should always use loops rather than manually writing out all of the operations like in your `println` statements.

If you can ask for the number of items before you start reading, you can allocate the array to be that size, then run both loops over the array length.

If you want to work with an unknown number of items, use a `List` of some sort. `ArrayList` lets you pick specific items out of the array in constant time. You'll need some way to indicate when you're done picking numbers.

Finally, unless sorting is the homework assignment, use `Arrays.sort` or `Collections.sort` instead of writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

use a java.util.ArrayList, it encapsulates the array class and should provide the functionality you need